# Mocking Laravel Eloquent models - Mocking model that is used in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I am trying to mock an eloquent model using the alias directive as follows:

```
$transporter = \Mockery::mock('alias:' . Transporter::class)
```

I have added the following annotations to the class

```
* @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
* @preserveGlobalState disabled
```

The problem is that in my `AppServiceProvider.php` I register my observer:

```
Transporter::observe(DefaultValuesObserver::class);
```

So when I comment this line out, the mocking works fine.
But when this line is present, I get a `Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock App\Models\Laravel\Transporter, class already exists`

* This is a filtered run of phpunit where only one class is ran.

I suppose that when calling observe, it is autoloading the transport class already.

So even when running everything in a seperate process, the class was already registered in the AppServiceProvider.

My current fix is to not use the alias but use the passthru to overcome the Eloquent issues:

```
$transporter = \Mockery::mock(Transporter::class)
            ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
            ->passthru()
            ->shouldReceive('setAttribute')
            ->passthru();
```

But this is not the best solution if I have to do this everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$mock = \Mockery::mock('overload:MyClass');`

For reference http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html?highlight=alias%3A#overloading